# How to place newly created View obj at top of fragment layout rather than bottom

Tags: android, android-fragments

My plan is to pass a picture or an `ImageView` and some text or a `TextView` from one `fragment` to another, where it will be displayed. The formatting needed to accomplish this goal would require the two `Views` to be placed above any existing `View` objects in the receiving `fragment` rather than below them. An example of what I am trying to accomplish would be how any new post made on Instagram is placed at the top of the feed rather than the bottom, as it would be if I were to simply add a new `ImageView` and `TextView` object to the `activity_layout.xml` file.

I need to know how to pass either the two `Views` or their contents to a second `fragment` and arrange its formatting to display the most recently added `Views` at the top of the screen. I already have the code to switch between fragments.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: the phrase "NEW" would suggest newer based on record-ID (integer) or perhaps time-stamp... am i getting the idea or i misinterpret your idea ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean (I'm still new to the Android SDK) but basically: the second `fragment` will have no `View` objects until the first passes one to it, if that's possible. Organizing the `Views` by time stamp from newest to oldest is basically what I am trying to do. Does that help?

Comment: there was a similar thread i read sometime ago, updated answer for you. hope this help.